# Non deterministic execution of boost filesystem directory_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

The following code recursively iterates over a given directory and prints its contents in the **same order** every time.

Is it possible to alter the directory iterator to print the directory contents in a random way (without i.e. using a vector to store the results and then print the vector contents randomly) ?

```
#include <string>

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  boost::filesystem::path dataPath("/home/test/");
  boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator endIterator;

  // Traverse the filesystem and retrieve the name of each root object found
  if (boost::filesystem::exists(dataPath) && boost::filesystem::is_directory(dataPath)) {
    for (static boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator directoryIterator(dataPath); directoryIterator != endIterator;
     ++directoryIterator) {
      if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(directoryIterator->status())) {

        std::string str = directoryIterator->path().string();
        cout << str << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Unless the iterator does some sorting itself, the order will be the order the operating system give you the file entries, most likely the order they are stored in the tables on the disk. If you want another order there's really no other way than the intermediate vector.

Answer (score 1):

Most OSes (e.g. Windows' [FindFirstFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050721-16/?p=34863/)) don't return entries in any particular order so there's no way to have them ordered as you want. Your best bet is to do the ordering/shuffling yourself.